# Aggregate rows with Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am looking for the best way to aggregate rows in Microsoft SQL (2008).
In PostgreSQL there is a function called [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) which is exactly doing what I want (and quite fast).

I did not find any similar predefined function in Microsoft SQL.
Whats the best practice to implement the function? Using temporary tables?

Comment: SQL Server is really weak at string formatting.  Search for "sql-server group_concat" for workarounds using SQL Server's `for xml` syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the way it works! Your keyword forwarded me to this page which helped me a lot: [GROUP_CONCAT in Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.dbsimplified.com/2011/06/groupconcat-in-microsoft-sql-server.html)